# How to get all child nodes of a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 3 types of nodes in my graph. i.e database(Yellow), table (red) and column(sky blue).

> - Database and tables are connected with HAS_TABLE relationship.
> - Table and columns are connected with HAS_COLUMNS relationship.
> - Databases are interconnected with LINKED_TO relationship.

[image: Database and tables are connected with HAS_TABLE relationship.]

I want to display all table and column nodes of particular databas. How can I get using node id.

I am trying cypher something like this. But its returnng all connected nodes

```
MATCH (n:db)<-[*]-(d) WHERE ID(n) = 113 RETURN d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the relationship types you do not want (i.e., `LINKED_TO`), you need to specify the relationship types you want *do* want:

```
MATCH (n:db)<-[:HAS_TABLE|HAS_COLUMN*]-(d)
WHERE ID(n) = 113
RETURN d
```

Comment: Its returning empty record

Comment: my bad.. Was using wrong relationship name. Working fine